# MySql:If i set binlog format to row,dose change buffer still valid？

Tags: mysql, sql-update, binlog

When i use "satement" binlog and non-unique index,mysql will use "change buffer" avoid reading from disk.
But if set binlog format to "row", binlog need the all columns in the row , so mysql must read from disk.So in this case , dose "change buffer" is invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-change-buffer.html):

> The change buffer is a special data structure that caches changes to
> **secondary index** pages when those pages are not in the buffer pool. The
> buffered changes, which may result from **INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE**
> operations (DML), are merged later when the pages are loaded into the
> buffer pool by other read operations.

This doc had made it very clear that `change buffer` could be used for `non-unique secondary index`.

Back to binlog of row format, it wouldn't affect `change buffer`. Because for `insert`, `update`, and `delete`, though `binlog` need the all columns in the row, those data could be gotten from cluster index and all non-unique indexes could still benefit from `change buffer`.

---

**Implementation**:

> `change buffer` is used to avoid too many random disk read. `redo log` is used to avoid too many random disk write.

Comment: Another question:Dose "change buffer" only used for secondary index?  when update or delete the cluster index data, dose mysql use "change buffer" to cache the page data about cluster index data?

Comment: The answer is `No`. "change buffer" only benifit for `non-unique secondary index`. For innodb, all data will be saved in `cluster index` (primary index). When insert a row into table, mysql have to check if primary key and other unique index keys are duplicated or not. With that said, it need to read page of cluster index into buffer pool and then check. Under that situation, `changed buffer` will not be used for those index. Most situations, the same as update and delete operations.

Comment: I think insert can't use change buffer , but update and delete may be has change to use ,because these two operation don't need to check the duplicate , or has other reason that can't use change buffer for delete or update operations.

Comment: @wenbin, `change buffer` is used for `insert` queries at first, then for `delete` and `update` queries.....  Innodb use B+Tree to store all data. Primary key will be with all other columns data and so that it's called cluster index. Other indexes of that table are also B+ Tree. When execuing insert or update queries, not only pages of cluster index need to be updated, but also pages of other inexes. That's why offical doc say `The change buffer is a special data structure that caches changes to secondary index pages when those pages are not in the buffer pool`

Comment: Welcome. If it's helpful for you, please don't fegot vote it up~